# How to rotate mesh which has "Clamp To" constraint

Tags: animation, transforms, constraints

I'm trying to use constraints to create animations like in the example:[image]

(I used shape keys in this example). I dont want to use shape keys since I want to use the moving parts as a target for the "Copy Location" constraint of another mesh.
I am trying to key frame influence of "Clamp To" constraint to make this animation:
[image]

Problem is that "Clamp To" affect mesh difrently when I am trying to duplicate and rotate around 3D Cursor mesh and curve(that is used as a target of "Clamp To" constraint of this mesh). I don't understand why it the mesh shifts relative to the curve while passing certain rotation value:

[image]

How to rotate the mesh and curve so mesh not change it position relative to curve? Or how can I make this animation using constraints?

[image]

Comment: Why constraints? Is the top image your desired result? Why not just animate in a parent's space? (Just parent an  item to an empty, duplicate/rotate the empties along with their children, then all items can be animated in the same axis).. or even just animate in Local space.

Comment: Thank you. I got the result this way